# Редирект с index.html

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, http-status-code-301

Вот так в данный момент выглядит .htaccess

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dom\.startnet\.info$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dom.startnet.info/$1 [R=301,L]
    #
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(index)\.(html)\ HTTP/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(index)\.(html)$ http://www.dom.startnet.info/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Переадресация с www. работает корректно, с index.html не работает.
При чем этот же код, если мы заменим index на default и изменим адрес страницы с index.html на default.html, работает корректно.

Сайтик самописный.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Объясните, что должен делать редирект с index.html и в каких случах. Ваш пример не слишком то читаемый.

Comment: с адреса www.dom.startnet.info/index.html должен перебрасывать на www.dom.startnet.info

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(index)\.(html)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(index)\.(html)$ http://www.dom.startnet.info/$1 [L,R=301]
```

на

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Попробовал, так тоже не работает.
Где какой то конфликт, но не могу понять где.

Comment: а если добавить `RewriteBase   /` в начало .htaccess?

Comment: Нет, тоже не работает. Где то наверное другой конфликт, буду разбираться, спасибо :)

Comment: Да, явно где то ещё. Применил данный редирект на age.su - работает как надо. Проблема у Вас в другом.